# Mongo Timed Out While Many Queries in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am facing a problem while executing very huge number (Thousands) of async queries to mongo 
I am getting the following error

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
MongoError: connection 4 to localhost:27017 timed out
```

I also tried different values of the connection options increasing and decreasing them but still getting the error

the connection code part in app.js

```
var MongoOptions = {
    socketTimeoutMS: 0,
    connectTimeoutMS: 0,
    keepAlive: true,
    reconnectTries: 30,
    poolSize: 10
};

mongoose.connect(Config.MONGO_DB_MOJ_CONNECTION, MongoOptions).then(function () {
    console.log('connected to mongo');
}, function (err) {
    //err handle
});
```

Comment: Your MongoDB obviously can't handle all those queries within a particular time frame, so the queries are timing out. Start looking at replication and/or sharding.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{  keepAlive: 0, connectTimeoutMS: 0}
```

Comment: plus , you must have in mind that mongo have lock system on records when using them, so your request can timeOut coz of that... so you should refactor your code according to mongo-s workflow logic to pass that problem.